# Looping text in Python with directional control

Tags: python, performance, python-2.x, animation, circular-list

The code is an implementation of looping text (similar to a circular buffer - wraps around when it reaches the edge of the defined bounds) with directional control.

The code is functional and works as intended, but I'm curious if there is anyway to improve the code even if it is only a small improvement (e.g. less garbage produced per loop cycle as a micro-optimisation, etc).

```
# cleaned up and improved prototype code for looping text scroll.
# added direction from the original code.

from sys import stdout
from time import sleep

global_shifted_text_array = []
global_text_length = 0

DIRECTION_LEFT_TO_RIGHT = -1
DIRECTION_RIGHT_TO_LEFT = 1

def set_text(text):
    global global_shifted_text_array
    global global_text_length

    global_shifted_text_array = pad_text(text)
    global_text_length = len(global_shifted_text_array)

def pad_text(text, padding = 5):
    text += ' ' * padding
    return list(text)

def shift_text(direction):
    global global_shifted_text_array
    range = xrange(global_text_length - 1, -1, -1) if direction == DIRECTION_LEFT_TO_RIGHT else xrange(global_text_length)

    # by the time the zero element is set in the for loop.
    # it is set to the last element (which is empty)
    # so we have to account for this by correcting for it.
    if direction == DIRECTION_RIGHT_TO_LEFT:
        first_element = global_shifted_text_array[0]

    for i in range:
        global_shifted_text_array[i] = global_shifted_text_array[((i + direction) % global_text_length)]
        # print 'global_shifted_text_array[{}] = global_shifted_text_array[{}]'.format(i, ((i + direction) % global_text_length))

    if direction == DIRECTION_RIGHT_TO_LEFT:
        global_shifted_text_array[global_text_length - 1] = first_element


def update_loop(direction = DIRECTION_LEFT_TO_RIGHT, frequency = 0.1):
    while 1:
        shift_text(direction)
        stdout.write('\r{0}'.format(''.join(global_shifted_text_array)))
        sleep(frequency)

set_text('Beautiful Lie')
update_loop()
```

Answer (score 1):

When I try it, it doesn't really work unless I add `stdout.flush()` after each `stdout.write()`.

The padding isn't controllable, as neither `set_text()` nor `update_loop()` accepts a `padding` parameter.

In my opinion, it should print the original text *before* performing the first shift.

Global variables are bad.  In this case, I'd eliminate them altogether by simplifying the code.  Take advantage of [`itertools.cycle()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) and Python's support for negative indexes.  I wouldn't bother with converting the string to a list and back to a string again.

`DIRECTION_LEFT_TO_RIGHT` is a bit verbose.  I suggest `SCROLL_RIGHT` instead.  "Frequency" sounds like it should go faster as the number increases: 10 Hz is faster than 1 Hz.  I suggest `period` as the name for the delay.

```
from itertools import cycle
from sys import stdout
from time import sleep

SCROLL_RIGHT = -1
SCROLL_LEFT = +1

def animate_text(text, scroll=SCROLL_RIGHT, period=0.5, padding=5):
    text += ' ' * padding
    for offset in cycle(xrange(0, scroll * len(text), scroll)):
        stdout.write('\r' + text[offset:] + text[:offset])
        stdout.flush()
        sleep(period)

animate_text('Beautiful Lie')
```

Comment: I intentionally avoiding using `itertools` as I plan on reimplementing this in C#, so I have avoided anything "pythonic". Thanks for the suggestions on naming I've taken that advice! By the way I think that `SCROLL_LEFT = +1` is verbose since the plus isn't needed.

Comment: If you're interested in C#, ask a follow-up question in C#. Don't let C#'s limitations force you to do silly things in Python.

Comment: Haha, I guess it is silly to implement it this way in Python but I have a preference for doing all prototyping in Python. Is there any equivalent of `itertools.cycle()` in C#?

Comment: If you have a C# question, then post a C# question.